# Calculating the volatility for Black Scholes

Tags: options, option-pricing, time-series, black-scholes

The following problem is from the book by Hull. I did it but I am not sure it is right. I am hoping that somebody here can tell me if I did it right and if not where I went wrong.

Thanks
Bob

Problem:

Suppose that observations on a stock price(in dollars) at the end of each
of $15$ consecutive weeks are as follows:

$ 30.2, \,\,\, 32, \,\,\, 31.1, \,\,\, 30.1, \,\,\, 30.2, \,\,\, 30.3,$
$30.6, \,\,\, 33.0, \,\,\, 32.9, \,\,\, 33.0, \,\,\, 33.5,$
$ \,\,\, 33.5, \,\,\,   33.7, \,\,\, 33.5, \,\,\, 33.2$

Estimate the stock price volatility. What is the standard error of your
estimate?

Answer:

$n + 1$ is the number of observations. $S_i$ is the value of the stock at
the end of the ith interval, $\tau$ is the length of the intervals
in years and $\hat{ {\sigma} }$ is a good estimate of the
standard deviation of $u_i$. The standard error of this estimate is about
$\frac{ \hat{ \sigma} }{ \sqrt{2n} }$.  The relevant formulas are:
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_i &=& \ln{( \frac{u_i}{u_{i-1}} )} \\
s &=&
    \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} {(u_i - \bar u)^2} } \\
\hat { \sigma } &=& \frac{s}{\sqrt{\tau} } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Note: $\bar u$ is the mean of the $u_i$ variables.
\newline
In this case, we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
n &=& 14 \\
u_1 &=& \ln {(\frac{32} {30.2} )} = 0.057894 \\
u_2 &=& \ln {(\frac{31.1} {32} )} = -0.02852 \\
u_3 &=& \ln {(\frac{30.1} {31.1} )} = -0.0326826 \\
u_4 &=& \ln {(\frac{30.2} {30.1} )} = 0.003316 \\
u_5 &=& \ln {(\frac{30.3} {30.2} )} = 0.003305 \\
u_6 &=& \ln {(\frac{30.6} {30.3} )} = 0.009852 \\
u_7 &=& \ln {(\frac{33 } {30.6} )} = 0.075507 \\
u_8 &=& \ln {(\frac{32.9} {33} )} = -0.003034 \\
u_9 &=& \ln {(\frac{33 } {32.9} )} = 0.003034 \\
u_{10} &=& \ln {(\frac{33.5 } {33} )} = 0.0150379 \\
u_{11} &=& \ln {(\frac{ 33.5 } {33.5} )} = 0 \\
u_{12} &=& \ln {(\frac{33.7 } {33.5} )} = 0.005952 \\
u_{13} &=& \ln {(\frac{33.5} {33.7} )} = - 0.0059524 \\
u_{14} &=& \ln {(\frac{33.2 } {33.5} )} = - 0.008995 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{i=5} {u_i} &=& 0.003312 \\
\sum_{i=6}^{i=10} {u_i} &=& 0.1064649 \\
\sum_{i=11}^{i=14} {u_i} &=& -0.0089954 \\
\sum_{i=0}^{i=14} {u_i} &=& 0.003312 + 0.1064649 -0.0089954 = 0.100781 \\
\bar u &=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} { u_i } =
    \frac{1}{14} { \sum_{i=1}^{i=14} { u_i } } = \frac{0.100781}{14} \\
\bar u &=& 0.007198 \\
s &=& \sqrt{ \frac{1}{14-1} \sum_{i=1}^{i=14} {(u_i - 0.007198)^2} } \\
(u_1 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.002570 \\
(u_2 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.001275 \\
(u_3 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.001590 \\
(u_4 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000151 \\
(u_5 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000152 \\
(u_6 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000070  \\
(u_7 - 0.007198)^2 &=&  0.0046661 \\
(u_8 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0001047  \\
(u_9 - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000173 \\
(u_{10} - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000615 \\
(u_{11} - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000518 \\
(u_{12} - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0000016  \\
(u_{13} - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0001729 \\
(u_{14} - 0.007198)^2 &=& 0.0002622  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{i=5} {(u_i - 0.007198)^2} &=& 0.0054653 \\
\sum_{i=6}^{i=10} {(u_i - 0.007198)^2} &=& 0.0048566 \\
\sum_{i=11}^{i=14} {(u_i - 0.007198)^2} &=& 0.0004885 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{i=14} {(u_i - 0.007198)^2} &=&
    0.0054653 + 0.0048566 + 0.0004885 = 0.0108104 \\
s &=& \sqrt{ \frac{1}{14-1} (0.0108104) } =
    \sqrt{ 0.0108104 } \\
s &=& 0.1039731 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
I am figuring that there are $52.1$ weeks in a year.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau &=& \frac{14}{52.1} = 0.268714 \\
\hat { \sigma } &=& \frac{s}{\sqrt{\tau} } =
    \frac{  0.1039731 } { \sqrt{  0.268714 } } = 0.200 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
My estimate of the volatility is $0.200$ and the standard error of this
estimate is $\frac{.200}{\sqrt{2(14)}} = 0.377$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thr second sum should be:

$$\sum_{i=6}^{10}u_i = 0.10039773$$

This gives a mean of $0.0067648$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma=.028836$.

To avoid these errors you should use something to automate your calculations. Something like a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for finding my arithmetic error. Except for that error is the method right?

Comment: Yes, the method is correct.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing the error in my arithmetic. I get: $\sum_{i=6}^{10} u_i = 0.0000070  + 0.0046661 + 0.0001047  + 0.0000173 + 0.0000615 = 0.0048566$ Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You're checking the wrong sum. Start with the part where you calculate the mean, $\bar{u}$. You calculate it to be 0.007198, but it should be 0.00676485 (up to some differences due to rounding).